# Como armar el tipo de codigo

Tags: javascript

recien estoy aprendiendo Javasc y me han pedido que haga este ejercicio:

Crear una condición que plasme lo siguiente:
Si "x" el precio del producto es menor o igual a 1500. se le aplica un interés del 15%.

gracias

Comment: No he intentado nada porque según la documentación que tengo solo hace referencia a (AND, OR, NOT).

Comment: bueno, muchas gracias.

Comment: Adjunta código para que obtengas una respuesta más concreta y especifica. Si no sabes por donde empezar, haz un condicional con la condición necesaria para el descuento y en ese bloque aplica la operación matemática para hacerle un descuento. Saludos